# Putting HTML text in certain positions but on the same line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am brand spanking new to HTML so please excuse the lack of knowledge. I am currently trying to set up a little website and I want to have three sections that a user can click on that will route the user to a different part of the website. Simply put, I want three sections, aligned left, center, and right that is able to be shown on the same line. Every time I am attempting this however, I set up one section on the left, and then I can get a section on the center and the right, but it is going on another line horizontally.

How can I get all three sections to be on the same horizontal line and simply just left, right and center?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: There are many ways to create grid layouts in HTML. They've been documented manifold. Please do some reading, choose an appropriate technique, and give it a try. Your question doesn't meet the standards of this network without having shown an effort and the related markup.

Comment: I would suggest looking up information on w3schools. This should be a nice starting point reference. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: Try to use bootstrap. Use the link, this might help you https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_ex1&stacked=h

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use `display: inline-block` although there are many ways to do this.
Suggest you look into [`flexbox`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) as this will make your future coding life a lot easier.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

#left,
#center,
#right {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#left {
  background-color: red;
}

#center {
  background-color: green;
}

#right {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='left'></div>
  <div id='center'></div>
  <div id='right'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #parent-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 500px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #left,
    #center,
    #right {
      width: 20%;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    #left {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    #center {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    #right {
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='parent-container'>
    <div id='left'>
      Left
    </div>

    <div id='center'>
      Center
    </div>

    <div id='right'>
      Right
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use bootstrap to align your divs.

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          One of three columns
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/